# my Xcode -- compile errors are just showing the red exclamation point

Tags: iphone, xcode, compiler-errors

I must have flipped a switch in my Xcode somewhere.  Now compile errors just show up with the red exclamation point at the left of the line with the error.  I no longer get the red bar that explains what is going on.  I can get it by clicking on the exclamation point, but I'd rather get that bar by default.

How can I change it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what you have selected inside..
View->Message Bubble - > it should be Show Issue...

Answer (score 0):

Try Preferences » Building » Message Bubbles » Show During Builds. You can also right-click on bubbles and find options there in the context menu.